# Assembly equivalent of array of function pointers?

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, nasm, bios

In C, if I wanted to call a function based on keyboard input, I would write something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char A(void) {
        return 'a';
}

char B(void) {
        return 'b';
}

char C(void) {
        return 'c';
}

char (*CHARS[])(void) = {A, B, C};
int main(void) {
        char calls[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        char c = CHARS[getc(stdin) - 'a']();
        printf("%c\n", c);
        return 0;
}
```

Can I make an array of calls in assembly? I am using `nasm` to compile a kernel if that fact has relevance.

**EDIT**
Playing around some more just now, I came up with:

```
        jmp main
f0:
f1:
f2:
        mov     ax, 0
main:
        mov     bx, fns
        add     bx, ax
        cmp     bx, 0
        je      end
        call    [bx]
        inc     ax
        jmp     main
        fns     dw f0, f1, f2, 0
end:
        hlt
```

Is the above correct (I'm literally like two days into assembly)?

Comment: Your updated code has the right idea. But: (1) you're assuming 16 bit addresses for everything. Is that what you want? (2) you can get rid of the use of `ax`. Assuming a 16 bit addressing mode, you want to add 2 to `bx` each time through your `main` loop, (3) you want to check whether `[bx]` is 0, not whether `bx` is 0. `bx` won't be 0 because it's a pointer into your address table.

Comment: @lurker Yes, it is 16 bit mode. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a jump table, and modify the PC (program counter) to jump to the right index in the table. For example

```
    ADD PC, $c      # Add index entered by the user to the PC
    BRA function_a
    BRA function_b
    BRA function_c
end_jump_table:
    # ...
```

And somewhere else:

```
function_a:
    # do your thing
    BRA end_jump_table
function_b:
    # do your thing
    BRA end_jump_table
function_c:
    # do your thing
    BRA end_jump_table
```

Not in any particular assembly language, but you get the idea.